# Why does my CSV export use semi-colons?

Tags: export

A simple search and then use the export option from the drop down generates me a csv file that isn't - i.e. it's a semi-colon separated values file, not commas. There doesn't seem to be any setting that does that, and it seems to be specific to one site.

CiviCRM 5.28.4, Drupal 7.73

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @samuelsolv for his answer to [Export contact info from MailChimp](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7138/export-contact-info-from-mailchimp)

Apparently, the separator for import/export of csv files is a "localization" setting, at this path:

/civicrm/admin/setting/localization?reset=1